# Powershell: Add node to XML root

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML file:

```
<shows>
    <breaking.bad />
    <stranger.things />
</shows>
```

And i want to modify it using powershell so it will become:

```
<shows>
    <breaking.bad />
    <stranger.things />
</shows>
<movies>
</movies>
```

I tried this and it did not work:

```
$doc = [xml](get-content "c:\list.xml")
$movies = $doc.createelement("movies")
$doc.appendchild($movies)
```

There's an error saying:
Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" argument (s): "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
At line:3 char:1
+     $doc.appendchild($movies)

Comment: Please provide an exact error message, and describe how your code is not working.

Comment: Edited with the error

Comment: Xml-files can only have a single root-node

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add another top level element, you need to add it to the container itself.

In order to make this work, I added a top level `Document` node, and then made `Shows` a child of that, like so.

```
[xml]$x = "
<document>
   <shows>
    <breaking.bad />
    <stranger.things />
  </shows>
</document>"
```

Then, I defined a new element just like you, by using the `CreateElement` method.  Finally, I added it to the Document.

```
$newElement = $x.CreateElement("movies")
$x.document.AppendChild($newElement)
```

And the output:

```
$x.OuterXml
<document><shows><breaking.bad /><stranger.things /></shows><movies /></document>
```